# Header resizing on scroll pure CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I make my own portfolio for school. But I may only CSS and HTML, no javascript. I want to resize my header when the visiter scrolls.

Example: http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/

Have someone an idea?

Thankyou!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Questions like this need to have the code you have already tried added to it, or it seems like you just want us to do it for you. As far as the actual question goes, I don't think it's possible to detect a scroll event with pure CSS.

Comment: Here is the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552728/resize-header-on-scroll

Comment: Indeed...this is not possible with CSS alone.

Answer (score 3):

You could create 2 headers, one full height, with `position: fixed`, and the other resized, and absolute positioned on top. You put the first one over the second, with z-index, and you're done.

You can't detect viewport position in a page with CSS.